# Windows 7 welcome screen: How to always reveal password

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, login-screen

On the Windows 7 Welcome Screen, I want all characters typed into the password box to be displayed (not masked) as the characters are being typed.  Is there a setting / registry key / third-party tool that can do this?

(Note that I am asking about the Welcome Screen specifically, not about password fields on websites.  Also, the reason I want to do this is because I am treating the password field as an opportunity to teach my son how to spell.)

Comment: Although I'm highly doubtful that is at all possible on Windows 7, I will be watching this question with interest.

Comment: wow ! i can believe that Windows has lot of security holes, but one like this would be unbelievable ! what's the goal for such a feature ??

Comment: This would be a security risk for the OS. So I think there is no such registry hack or 3rd party programm, but lets see if someone knows more.

Comment: You could be teaching your son in so many other ways how to spell. Why would you want to do this at the Welcome Screen ?????

Comment: @Rik - I thought I might get that question.  I am, of course, teaching him typing and spelling in many other ways, but why not squeeze in extra reinforcement where possible?

Comment: @user219672 - The lack of password masking in a field is only a security concern if you cannot enable it.  Otherwise password masking is useless if you are alone in a room.

Answer (score -1):

You need Windows 8+ for the "show password being typed" option (that looks like a little eye in the text field). Now, it is not physically impossible to hack winlogon.exe and have it display clear text, I don't think anyone has done that yet.